Use: Border vs. BoxView .NET MAUI
The summary of a Border according to the documentation is

The .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) Border is a container control that draws a border, background, or both, around another control. A Border can only contain one child object. If you want to put a border around multiple objects, wrap them in a container object such as a layout. For more information about layouts, see Layouts.

And the summary of a BoxView is as follows

The .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) BoxView draws a simple rectangle or square, of a specified width, height, and color.

If you pay attention, you can understand the difference between these control. The first,  contains and involve another control (only one). The second, displays a visual element. So, to get a solid decision to use on of them what I need to consider? I mean the features of each control? Their performance?
For example. In order to draw a border and set a specific color around a Entry control (To this step lets take a part the default Entry background color). Which is the best option?

A Border can be a container for other content, while a BoxView cannot.  If you need to wrap other content, you should use Border
